# Cannot Create A DbSet for ApplicationUser

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have an asp.net core project that I am refactoring. Previously I had all my database logic contained within the project, however as we are now adding a WebAPI, I have moved the database logic to a separate .net core standard project, so it is shared between the two projects.

This seems to work fine in the new web api, however I am having issues in the original project, relating to signInManager and the ApplicationUser class.

All compiles just fine, however, I get the following error during runtime:

```
InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a DbSet for 'ApplicationUser' because this type is not included in the model for the context.`
```

I have also moved this ApplicationUser class to the new DAL project, and as far as I can see, i've updated all references to it (certainly enough to pass the compile time checks).

My startup.cs is as follows:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // password policy settings
        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Password settings
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 6;

            // Lockout settings
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

            // User settings
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

        });

        // Add session cookie
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Cookie settings
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            // If the LoginPath isn't set, ASP.NET Core defaults 
            // the path to /Account/Login.
            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            // If the AccessDeniedPath isn't set, ASP.NET Core defaults 
            // the path to /Account/AccessDenied.
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;

            // Disable redirect to login page for unauthorized requests to / api resources
            options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && context.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status200OK)
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
                    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
                }
            };

        });

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

        // add our Db handlers
        services.AddScoped<DAL.Services.Interfaces.IServices, DAL.Services.Services>();

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IServiceProvider services)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });


    }


}
```

I have a "using" statement at the top as follows:

`using IceBowl.DAL;
using IceBowl.DAL.Models;`

So the call to "AddIdentity" is passing in the right `ApplicationUser` - in fact, there is only one ApplicationUser class, I deleted the original.

The code seems to be having issues on the following line:

`var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);`

There's something it doesnt like about sign in manager, but I'm at a loss to explain what. All references have been updated and now point to the DAL that contains the datacontext and ApplicationUser class.

Any pointers?

Comment: Have you referenced `ApplicationUser` from new DAL to `DbContext` in original project?

Comment: where do I need to reference it? It's not used anywhere in the DbContext. Neither is it referenced in the old DbContext before I moved it to a separate project.

Comment: Not sure how you implement your current project, you may consider sharing us a demo to reproduce your issue.